# How to create a signature in jmeter, using beanshell preprocessor

Tags: javascript, encryption, jmeter, digital-signature, signature

I need to create a signature in jmeter from a function in javascript:

```
'x-signature': cipher.createSignature(stringCipheredBody, randomKey)
```

I have already calculated the value of both variables, I need to create a method to create the signature, "randomKey" corresponds to a random AES key and "stringCipheredBody" corresponds to a Json Body encrypted in String Format

In my Jmeter Code i have:

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
...
String xSignature = cipher.createSignature(stringCipheredBody, randomKey);
```

but I get the following error: "Typed variable declaration : Attempt to resolve method: createSignature() on undefined variable or class name: cipher"

please i need help

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't use Beanshell especially for cryptographic operations, it's some form of a performance anti-pattern, [since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting). More information: [Beanshell vs. JSR223 vs. Java For JMeter: Complete Showdown](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-jmeter)
2. Prior to using `cipher` object you need to instantiate it first, something like:

   ```
   Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
   ```
3. There is no Cipher.createSignature() function, see the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html) for all available methods. Java != JavaScript hence you cannot paste functions and hope that they will work especially if they rely on 3rd-party libraries. So determine the encryption algorithm somehow and re-implement it in Groovy, see [Encryption and decryption with Groovy](https://groovy.apache.org/blog/encryption-and-decryption-with-groovy) guide for some example code.